# Cassandra bounding box search

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am looking to use Cassandra for a nearby search type query. based on my lon/lat coordinates I want to retrieve the closest points. I do not need 100% accuracy so I am comfortable in using a bounding box instead of a circle (better performance too), but I can't find concrete instructions (Hopefully with an example) how to implement a bounding box.

Comment: Do you already have designed datamodel?

Comment: No I do not have a model yet.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, there's no easy way to have a generic geospatial index search on top of Cassandra. I believe you only have two options:

- [Geohashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash), split your dataset into square/rectangular elements: for example, use integer parts of lat/lon as an indexes in a grid. Upon doing search, you can load all elements in an enclosing grid element and perform full neighbour scan inside your application.

  - works well if you have an evenly distributed dataset, like grid points  in [NWP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_weather_prediction) similation that I've had.
  - works really bad on a datasets like "restaurants in USA", where most of the points are herding around large cities. You'll have unbalanced high load on different grid elements like New York area and get absolutely empty index buckets located somewhere in the Atlantic Ocean.
- External indexes like [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/)/[Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)/Sphinx/etc.

  - All of them have geospatial indexing support out-of-the-box, no need to develop your own in your application layer.
  - You have to setup a separate indexing service and keep cassandra/index data in sync. There's some cassandra/search integrations like [DSE](http://www.datastax.com/products/products-index) (commercial), [stargate-core](http://stargate-core.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (I've never heard about anyone using this in production), or you can roll your own, but all of these require time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was touched on in the Euro Cassandra Summit in 2014.

[RedHat: Scalable Geospatial Indexing with Cassandra](http://www.planetcassandra.org/video-presentations/vp/cassandra-summit-europe-2014/vd/redhat-scalable-geospatial-indexing-with-cassandra/)

The presenter explains how he created a spatial index using User Defined Types that is very suitable to querying geospatial data using a region or bounding box based lookup.

The general idea is to break up your data into regions that are defined by bounding boxes. Each region then represents a rowkey, which you can then use to access any data associated with that region. If you have a location of interest, you query the keyspace on the regions which fall inside that area.